# How to setup kafka a cluster using confluent docker images

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I tried to setup 3 node kafka cluster using confluent docker images.

https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka

https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper

```
docker run -d --restart always --name zk-1 -e zk_id=1 -e zk_server.1=ip1:2888:3888 -e zk_server.2=ip2:2888:3888 -e zk_server.3=ip3:2888:3888 -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1-1
docker run -d --restart always --name zk-2 -e zk_id=2 -e zk_server.1=ip1:2888:3888 -e zk_server.2=ip2:2888:3888 -e zk_server.3=ip3:2888:3888 -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1-1
docker run -d --restart always --name zk-3 -e zk_id=3 -e zk_server.1=ip1:2888:3888 -e zk_server.2=ip2:2888:3888 -e zk_server.3=ip3:2888:3888 -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1-1
docker run -d --restart always --name kafka-1 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://ip1:9092 -p 9092:9092 confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1-1
docker run -d --restart always --name kafka-2 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -p 9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://ip2:9092 confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1-1
docker run -d --restart always --name kafka-3 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -p 9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://ip3:9092 confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1-1
```

But when I form the cluster I see 1 or 2 brokers instead of all 3 brokers that I formed.

`docker run -it --net host confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -L`

Did I need to set [bootstrap.server](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-properties-bootstrap-servers.html) property while forming the cluster if that is the case I don't see it mentioned in the confluent [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration).

Logs

```
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,788] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,793] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-ElectPreferredLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,801] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,850] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,868] INFO Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/1 is: 565,565,1559801526862,1559801526862,1,0,0,72057595854848009,196,0,565
 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,870] INFO Registered broker 1 at path /brokers/ids/1 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(ip1,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT)), czxid (broker epoch): 565 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,871] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /var/lib/kafka/data/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,934] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1] Starting (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,943] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,949] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,958] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,960] DEBUG [Controller id=1] Broker 2 has been elected as the controller, so stopping the election process. (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,966] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,966] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,970] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-06-06 06:12:06,983] INFO [ProducerId Manager 1]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:1,blockStartProducerId:9000,blockEndProducerId:9999) by writing to Zk with path version 10 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,004] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,005] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,007] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,031] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,044] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Started data-plane processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,048] INFO Kafka version: 2.2.0-cp2 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,068] INFO Kafka commitId: 00d486623990ed9d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,072] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,078] INFO Waiting until monitored service is ready for metrics collection (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,082] INFO Monitored service is now ready (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,082] INFO Attempting to collect and submit metrics (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,108] TRACE [Broker id=1] Cached leader info PartitionState(controllerEpoch=5, leader=2, leaderEpoch=1, isr=[2], zkVersion=1, replicas=[2], offlineReplicas=[]) for partition __confluent.support.metrics-0 in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 2 epoch 6 with correlation id 0 (state.change.logger)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,322] WARN The replication factor of topic __confluent.support.metrics is 1, which is less than the desired replication factor of 3.  If you happen to add more brokers to this cluster, then it is important to increase the replication factor of the topic to eventually 3 to ensure reliable and durable metrics collection. (io.confluent.support.metrics.common.kafka.KafkaUtilities)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,334] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://ip1:9092, PLAINTEXT://ip2:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 10000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,366] INFO Kafka version: 2.2.0-cp2 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,366] INFO Kafka commitId: 00d486623990ed9d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,399] INFO Cluster ID: 0DmmTlnXQMGD52urD7rxuA (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,449] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
[2019-06-06 06:12:07,459] INFO Successfully submitted metrics to Kafka topic __confluent.support.metrics (io.confluent.support.metrics.submitters.KafkaSubmitter)
[2019-06-06 06:12:08,470] INFO Successfully submitted metrics to Confluent via secure endpoint (io.confluent.support.metrics.submitters.ConfluentSubmitter)
```

As you can see `bootstrap.servers` is automatically populated to just `ip1` and `ip2`. While `ip3` is missing.

Comment: If you use docker -p 9092:9092 for several containers it will not work because you try to map several container internal port to the same host port. Also I would recommend you use docker compose to create your cluster...

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, this already exists within a Compose file

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.2-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml

However, I think it assumes your host is Linux, as that's only where `network: host` is going to work, as expected

---

In any case, some notes

- For example, `ip1` doesn't exist... it would have to be `zk-1` the hostname of that container
- Start simpler. Get one broker running, and you can run many brokers with one Zookeeper
- You cannot map the same ports on the same host ... see each usage of `-p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888` (2888 and 3888 actually don't need exposed to your host), similarly for `-p 9092:9092`
- `--net host` shouldn't be necessary to use `kafkacat` if you added all containers to the same `--network` (like Docker compose would do)
- Starting many brokers on one host machine doesn't add many "benefits"

Comment: I'm trying kakfa cluster on three different ec2 machines, not on a single machine using docker-compose.

Comment: Okay fine. Have you tried getting that working without Docker first? After that, it's just setting up the correct networking rules with port mapping from the containers, and don't forget about persistent volumes.